# Python threadings: threads block

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

im checking my customers countries so as to i know which service i can offer bla bla......
so the the problems is the threads blocks for example it check 15-20 and block, i want a solution to keep it continuing
the code is:

```
import requests
import re
from sys import argv
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread


e = argv[1]

emails = open(e, 'r').readlines()
emails = map(lambda s: s.strip(), emails)

valid=[]

def base(email):
    xo = requests.get("http://www.paypal.com/xclick/business="+email,     headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.0; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"}).text
    x = re.search("s.eVar36=\"(.*?)\";", xo)
    try:
        if x.group(1) != "":
            print "%s === %s" % (email,x.group(1))
            w=open(str(x.group(1))+".txt", 'a')
            w.write(email+"\n")
            valid.append(email)
    except:
        pass

def work():
    email=q.get()
    base(email)
    q.task_done()

THREADS = 25
q=Queue()

for i in range(THREADS):
    t=Thread(target=work())
    t.daemon=True
    t.start()

if (len(argv)>0):
    for email in emails:
        q.put(email)
    q.join()`enter code here
```

thanks in advance

Comment: hello i need some help

Comment: Check out this line: `t=Thread(target=work())` You called the function before creating the thread. Instead you should do `t=Thread(target=work)`.

Comment: Your worker only processes one email which seems odd. Consider using `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`.

Comment: same as threading?

Comment: Yes, it builds a pool of threads and then there are multiple methods for running jobs on the queue. `multiprocessing` implements a subprocess based `Pool` class and a threaded based cousin.

Comment: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'ThreadPool'

Comment: `import multiprocessing.pool` (little 'p') then do `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool()` (little 'p' again). `multiprocessing.Pool` is the multi-processing version. I find myself saying its "pool" not "Pool" - LOL

Comment: can u give an example? im kinda dumb in multiprocessing

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you call `work()` instead of passing the `work` function when creating your threads. Instead of putting changes in your code, consider moving the python's `ThreadPool` which does the heavy lifting for you. Here's an example that implements what you want.

`map` calls your worker for each email in the iterator and returns the worker's result as an iterator (python 3) or list (python 2). Your worker returns a valid email or None for each email its given, so you just have to filter out the Nones at the end.

```
import requests
import re
from sys import argv
import multiprocessing.pool

e = argv[1]

emails = [line.strip() for line in open(e)]


def base(email):
    print("getting email {}".format(email))
    try:
        xo = requests.get("http://www.paypal.com/xclick/business="+email,     headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.0; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"}).text
        x = re.search("s.eVar36=\"(.*?)\";", xo)
        try:
            if x.group(1) != "":
                print "%s === %s" % (email,x.group(1))
                with open(str(x.group(1))+".txt", 'a') as w:
                    w.write(email+"\n")
                return email
        except:
            pass
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)

THREADS = 25
pool = multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(THREADS)
valid = [email for email in pool.map(base, emails, chunksize=1) if email]
print(valid)
pool.close()
```

Comment: it keep blocking again same as without Pool

Comment: The place it blocks is at `pool.map`, is that a problem? You want your code to continue? I assume you want the `valid` list sometime and you also don't want to exit before the work is done. You could put the pool work in its own thread and continue on your way.

Comment: requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.paypal.com', port=80): Max retries exceed
ed with url: /xclick/business=dizzymunt@aol.com (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.
connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x023E0770>, 'Connection to www.paypal.com timed out. (connect timeout
=10)'))
Exception in thread Thread-22 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):Exception in thread Thread-
10 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):           ------------------------    this is error is caused because of website right?

Comment: Exceptions in the worker are re-raised in `pool.map` and since we don't catch them, the program exits. I updated the example to catch and print `requests` errors. I also added a print for each email just in case.

Comment: it doesn(t genereate the error as u wrote in except.... its paste lot of emails and write about 3 or 4 in the files instead of alot.....

Comment: There could be other problems with the request or the data you scan for... can you give me a sample email that doesn't work? You could also expand your generic exception a bit to `except Exception as e: print(e)` to see what else goes wrong.